# Help Getting a Zero out of the Denominator of a Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is the following limit equal to $1/2$. I get undefined. :-(

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x+1)^{1/2}+1}x$$

this should $= 1/2$.

When I multiply the top and bottom by $(x+1)^{1/2} - 1$, I end up with this...

On the numerator: $x+1-1$

On the denominator: $x\Big((x+1)^{1/2} -1\Big)$

This then gets

On the numerator: $1$

On the denominator: $(x+1)^{1/2} -1$

But when as $x\to 0$, the denominator still has a zero! Could someone please help?

Comment: Probably it should have been $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}$.

Comment: @Daniel: No, it’s $+1$, which I inadvertently dropped on the initial edit.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But with a $+1$, the limit is $\infty$, while with a $-1$, it would be $\frac12$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Then certainly the limit is not $1/2$.

Comment: @Peter: That’s perfectly true, but you can check the original post to see that the function was indeed given with $+1$ in the numerator (and therefore does not in fact have limit $\frac12$).

Comment: This helps. Thanks. Copying error! Ugh. It is minus one at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}$ then:

$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$

As $x$ goes to $0$ this goes $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Check the numerator again: you end up with $x$: $\;\;x + 1 - 1 = x$. That term then cancels with the factor of $x$ in the denominator.

$$\frac{(x+1)^{1/2}+1}x\cdot \dfrac{(x+ 1)^{1/2} - 1}{(x+ 1)^{1/2} - 1} = \dfrac {x + 1 - 1}{x(x+ 1)^{1/2} - 1)} = \dfrac{1}{(x + 1)^{1/2}} $$

And now we conclude that the limit of $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{(x + 1)^{1/2}-1} \to \frac {1}{0}$$

That is, as $x \to 0$, the denominator get's incredibly small, so small that the limit blows up to infinity. Recall that a we don't actually have division by $0$; that is, we are not evaluating the function **at** zero. What we have is the limit as $x \to 0$, as $x$ gets very very close to zero, but not equal to zero.
That is: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{(x + 1)^{1/2}-1} = +\infty$$

Comment: The OP already did that; the remaining factor in the denominator goes to $0$.

Comment: @Brian I see that now.

Comment: Thanks, @Amzoti. How'd I miss that?!

Comment: @amWhy: You are welcome and I do it all the time! :-) +1